Macro expansion crashes oddly
Here is my mwe.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\test{\textnormal{test}}

\newcounter{wordCount}
\setcounter{wordCount}{0}
\newcounter{AllWord}
\setcounter{AllWord}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\exy}{ m m m}{%
    \StrCount{#2}{,}[\comma]
    \StrCount{#2}{?}[\qmark]
    \ifthenelse{\qmark > 0}{%
        \addtocounter{wordCount}{\comma + \qmark}
        \addtocounter{AllWord}{\comma + \qmark}
    }{%
        \addtocounter{wordCount}{\comma + \qmark + 1}
        \addtocounter{AllWord}{\comma + \qmark + 1}
    }
    \textbf{#2} (#3), ``#1''\\%
}

\begin{document}
    \test\par
    \exy{one \test}{two \test s}{three \test s}
\end{document}

If you comment out the line with \exy it works as expected. Otherwise the errors start with
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/hsmye/LaTeX/Gaelic/vocab/mwe.tex",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined control sequence.\n\\reserved@a ->\\@nil",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]

which is beyond my macro-fu. Can someone help? It should be noted that this is not the original problem. To produce an MWE without requiring font purchase, I kept taking out until there was no error, then added back to get this. The original problem was:
\newfontfamily{\EtGoudy}{P22 Goudy Ampersands}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\GoudyEt}{\EtGoudy}
\newfontfamily{\cVirgi}{P22 Virginian}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\Virgic}{\cVirgi}
\def\dispEt{\GoudyEt{c}\kern -3pt{\vspace{-0.01ex}\huge\Virgic{c}}.}
\def\Etc{\textnormal{\dispEt}}

replace \test with \Etc with similar results.

It would be better to explain what you're trying to do. But two thinks must be noted. 1. \StrCount tries fulll expansion and \textnormal doesn't survive it. 2. \addtocounter{foo}{<number>} does not perform arithmetic in the second argument.

@egreg \StrCount or an equivalent is required. Do you know of a less destructive replacement?

@egreg Regards \addtocounter it does if you include the calc package. I think…

I don't think fonts have anything to do with the problem. But if you don't explain your intentions, it's impossible to help.

@egreg, the intention was to include a custom 'Etc.' in the expansion. I have a project that needs to be consistent with other text. I modified my posting with the original needed macro, i.e. \Etc.

\def\dispEt{\GoudyEt{c}\kern -3pt{\vspace{-0.01ex}\huge\Virgic{c}}.}  is a very strange construct it typesets c then backs up, then saves a negative vertical space to be added after after this line after the current paragraph has been broken in to lines, then typesets another large c ?

it may perhaps be enough to use \protected\def rather than \def everywhere, also you are missing %  from many lines, and the \vspace probably should be removed.

@DavidCarlisle, the 'c' is actually an ampersand, and the second 'c' is being added. I can certainly add the \protected.

yes i guessed from the name of the command, but still you are adding vertical space at a completely different point on the document, depending on line breaking in the paragraph where this appears

I have to tell you that I've forgotten why I did that! Generally, I fiddle with things until they work—I have no particular plan other than the obvious. BTW, could you write up the suggestion about \protected as an answer, because it worked like a charm!

Note you should always show TeX errors in multi-line form as the linebreaks are vital to understand the message, they mark which command is undefined
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ->\@nil 
                    
l.29 ...exy{one \test}{two \test s}{three \test s}
                                                  
?

You used a TeX primitive definition, resulting in a fragile command which breaks in an expansion context. If you use \NewDocumentCommand you get \protected command safe in such constructs.
This runs without error

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{}{\textnormal{test}}

\newcounter{wordCount}
\setcounter{wordCount}{0}
\newcounter{AllWord}
\setcounter{AllWord}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\exy}{ m m m}{%
    \StrCount{#2}{,}[\comma]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \StrCount{#2}{?}[\qmark]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ifthenelse{\qmark > 0}{%
        \addtocounter{wordCount}{\comma + \qmark}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \addtocounter{AllWord}{\comma + \qmark}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }{%
        \addtocounter{wordCount}{\comma + \qmark + 1}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \addtocounter{AllWord}{\comma + \qmark + 1}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    }%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \textbf{#2} (#3), ``#1''\\%
}

\begin{document}
    \test\par
    \exy{one \test}{two \test s}{three \test s}
\end{document}

But produces
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 29--30

Due to the mis-placed \\  which should never be used at the end of a paragraph. (It would be better to use \par)

I'll revise using your suggestions. Good points all, incremental additions to my LaTeX knowledge—thanks!

I'd not use xstring. The main problem in your code is that the command \Etc is (very) fragile.
My proposal is to use expl3 in order to count commas and question marks, by splitting the text at them and counting the items (and subtracting one).
The argument is fully expanded (but robust command aren't) and “purified”, so commands such as \textnormal disappear.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newcommand\test{\textnormal{test}}
\NewDocumentCommand\dispEt{}{\GoudyEt{c}\kern -3pt{\huge\Virgic{c}}.}
\NewDocumentCommand\Etc{}{\textnormal{\dispEt}}
\newcommand\GoudyEt{}% just for testing
\newcommand{\Virgic}{}% just for testing

\newcounter{wordCount}
\newcounter{AllWord}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\exy}{m m m}
 {
  \hsmyers_xyz_exy:nnen { #1 } { #2 } { \text_purify:n { \text_expand:n { #2 } } } { #3 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int
\int_new:N \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hsmyers_xyz_exy:nnnn
 {
  \hsmyers_xyz_count:nnN { , } { #3 } \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int
  \hsmyers_xyz_count:nnN { ? } { #3 } \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int
  \int_compare:nTF { \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int > 0 }
   {
    \addtocounter{wordCount}
     {
      \int_eval:n { \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int + \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int }
     }
    \addtocounter{AllWord}
     {
      \int_eval:n { \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int + \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int }
     }
    }{%
    \addtocounter{wordCount}
     {
      \int_eval:n { \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int + \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int + 1}
     }
    \addtocounter{AllWord}
     {
      \int_eval:n { \l_hsmyers_xyz_comma_int + \l_hsmyers_xyz_qmark_int + 1}
     }
   }
  \textbf{#2}~#4,~``#1''
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hsmyers_xyz_exy:nnnn { nne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hsmyers_xyz_count:nnN
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \int_set:Nn #3 { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq - 1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test\par

\exy{one \Etc}{two \test \Etc{} s}{three \Etc{} s}

wordCount=\the\value{wordCount}

AllWord=\the\value{AllWord}

\exy{one \test}{two, three?}{three \test s}

wordCount=\the\value{wordCount}

AllWord=\the\value{AllWord}

\end{document}



Thank you for a better approach to parsing the argument! I'll use it shortly. It has been a very educational day.
